# infowindow.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: f.get is not a function in react component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I use this code in React Component 
The goal of this logics is after click show infowindow

```
clickInfoWindow = (event, element) => { 
    const { map } = this.state;
    let placeID = event.currentTarget.id;
    let { allMarkers, InfoWindow } = this.state;
    let infowindow = InfoWindow.find(infowindow=>infowindow.marker.id == placeID)
    let marker = infowindow.marker;
    console.log(marker, infowindow);
    infowindow.open(marker, map)
    this.closeInfowindow();
}
```

I've create object infowindow with google maps constructor in another component.(Click [here component in gist](https://gist.github.com/Natanagar/f0f08fe300a849aefe170d837a4d9bfb)!

[App.js](https://gist.github.com/Natanagar/9fcc89f3dac9da6efb2fb51375e0652b)

Comment: Please show us the code of the component you have written. What kind of object is `infowindow` in your example and what should calling `open()` on it do?

Comment: why don't you use react-google-maps as it is component based and it's  community is huge.

Comment: added code to question